# How to extract data using pattern and matcher

Tags: java, string, url

Hey i am trying to map old URLs to new url. Like -

`/oldapp/viewReview.do?action=show_references&bugId=xy12&queueName=OLLD-CodeReviews`

to - `newapp/review/reference?bugId=xy12&queueName=OLLD-CodeReviews`

How i can use Pattern and Matcher to match the pattern and extract bugId and queueName from URL. please help.

Comment: I think you can use lookbehinds like `"(?<=queueName=).*"` to capture the value of queueName

Answer (score 1):

Any characters followed by `?` or `&` followed by the identifier, `=`, and the value which cannot contain `&` as a group, and then any trailing characters:

```
Pattern bugidp = Pattern.compile(".*[?&]bugId=([^&]+).*");
Pattern queuep = Pattern.compile(".*[?&]queueName=([^&]+).*");
Matcher bugidm = bugidp.matcher(url);
Matcher queuem = queuep.matcher(url);
if (bugid.matches() && queuem.matches()) {
    String bugid = bugidm.group(1);
    String qname = queuem.group(1);
    String newrl = String.format("newapp/review/reference?bugId=%s&queueName=%s",
            bugid, qname);
} else {
    // not found
}
```